# Rich Text Box C# Winforms - Do not highlight word if contained inside another

Tags: c#, winforms, find

I am using C# Winforms with a rich text box. I am using the find method to highlight a word inside the text, basically for a spell checker. The problem I am having is that I do not wish to highlight a word if it is contained inside another word. Here is an example:

Text = This is an erro. This is a second erro.
Searching for "erro" in the string. The first error is corrected to "error"
Text = This is an error. This is a second erro.

Now when I search for "erro" it highlights it like:

this is an **erro**r. This is a second erro.

Is it possible to actually only highlight the word only if it is not contained inside another word? Or in other words is it possible to check to see if it is contained inside another so it can be skipped?

```
// Find the word.
ocrText.Find(this.ocrWords[wordToFindIndex], index, ocrText.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);

//TODO: Check to see if the found word is not contained inside another word
```

Thanks.

Comment: You'll first have to a make a solid definition of "word".  Look at the character to the left and the right of the match.  Arbitrarily, if char.IsLetter() returns true for these characters then skip it.

Comment: Do you mean the *Match whole word* feature as in *Find* dialog of VS editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the overloaded RichTextBox.Find method with the RichTextBoxFinds Enumeration
Specifically RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord.

```
ocrText.Find(this.ocrWords[wordToFindIndex], index, ocrText.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord );
```

Comment: that's really strange. I did actually try using this earlier but it did not work. Oh well it does now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution would be to test the characters behind and in front of your word.
For instance you could test if the next/previous character is a whitespace or start/end of line.